# Let receivers of an email reply to a different address

Tags: python, django, gmail

Am using gmail smtp to send email messages and  it works fine. The only problem is that I want  receipients of the email to reply to a different email address. In other words I send them an email as from `me@gmail.com` but when they click reply the message should be replied to `another@gmail.com` or `another@yahoo.com`. How can I accomplish this please.

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

In my `views.py` I have:

```
email = EmailMessage(
            subject='Registration Successful',
            body=msg,
            from_email='My Name <me@gmail.com>',
            to='recipient@gmail.com')
        email.send()
```

This works but the recipient replies to `me@gmail.com`. I want the recipient to reply to `another@gmail.com`. Please What do I need to do to this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `Reply-To` header to the email:

```
email = EmailMessage(
            subject='Registration Successful',
            body=msg,
            from_email='My Name <me@gmail.com>',
            to='recipient@gmail.com',
            headers={'Reply-To': 'another@gmail.com'})
email.send()
```

Comment: This works but gmail does not listen to the reply to field. Even though it shows there the address to reply to, on clicking "reply", the senders email is what appears specified reply email

Comment: Have you tried with a third party email, rather than sending to yourself? According to gmail docs, gmail doesn't respect the `Reply-To` header when you reply to one of your own messages.

Comment: From the gmail forums: _Gmail always respects the reply-to when replying except when you reply to one of your own messages._

Comment: @YehonathanQuartey - this is possibly a quirk (bug?) with the way GMail handles the headers in certain situations - see [this blog post](http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2011/3/30/getting-gmail-recognize-reply-header/). Edit: beaten somewhat, but the link may be useful.

Comment: Oh silly me. It works. What I did was try to send an email to myself and set the reply to another@gmail.com. Gmail noticed it was still me hence the Reply-to specification did not work. I wonder if there is a way around this. Hmmm

Comment: Of course the way around this is to set up a dummy email and use that as an itermediary! Very unelegant